# Convert string with nested delimiters into a map

Tags: scala

I want to turn this String:

`"1:a|2:b|3:c"`

into this:

`Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c")`

I have a procedural method that works, but it seems there ought to be a more functional approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val a = [YOUR STRING]
a.split('|').map(_.split(':')).map(a => (a(0) -> a(1))).toMap
```

Comment: `.map { val pair = _.split(':'); pair(0) -> pair(1) }.toMap` would be slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
val s = "1:a|2:b|3:c"

"(\\d+)\\:(\\w+)".r.findAllMatchIn(s).map( m => (m.group(1).toInt -> m.group(2)) ).toMap
```